# Swagger: Authorization token is not passed into requests headers

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, springfox

i use springfox 2.9.2
I have api like:

```
@Api(tags = "Users")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UsersController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Creates a user")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "user created"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "not authorized")})

    @PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public ResponseEntity addUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
...
}
```

to make this call user needs authorization token
Authorization: Bearer {token}

witch comes from authentication server. 
i try to make first call to this server in swagger and pass it to controller requests like the one above.
So i do

```
@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        final String swaggerToken = "";
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            @Bean
    public      .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.mbv.coros.notification.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo())
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securityScheme()))
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

private SecurityScheme securityScheme() {
        GrantType grantType = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(AUTH_SERVER + "/token");

SecurityScheme oauth = new OAuthBuilder().name("spring_oauth")
                .grantTypes(Arrays.asList(grantType))
                .scopes(Arrays.asList(scopes()))
                .build();
        return oauth;

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
                .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .build();
    }

    List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
                = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Lists.newArrayList(
                new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
    }
```

on Swagger ui authorization call returns the token successfully but it doesnt add it to request headers. It generates

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/users/get" -H "accept: */*"
```

if i set token like:

```
.securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
 private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "header");
    }
```

it works perfectly.
any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Similar issue here. Could you solve this issue?

Comment: We're currently using the implicit flow for Swagger, but the token is not passed to service.
Also, nobody calls getTokenName: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/search?q=getTokenName&unscoped_q=getTokenName

Comment: Swagger is not supposed to set the auth token directly; So, you are supposed to copy the token and set it using the "Authorize" button that appears on the top right.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Swagger uses token only if you configure it to do so, and the configuration is done using the "Authorize" button on the top right of the Swagger UI page.

So, the ideal case would be:

1. Trigger Auth call which returns the token
2. Copy the token; Click on "Authorize" button and paste the JWT token in "Bearer "

After this, all the subsequent calls are supposed to use this token until you press logout.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your answer. The "Authorize" button will perform the login and returns the access token in the browser URL, AFAIK. But then Swagger should extract the token from the URL and pass it in the Authorization Bearer header field

Comment: I don't know if Swagger sends the auth call directly. I see that you are using JWT and I have the same setup as your example, and I usually copy and paste the token in the Authorize pop-up, which contains a textbox for the token. And all other call works with that. You can have a look at this: https://petstore.swagger.io/ - I am talking about the first one which says api_key.